# Determine vegetation percentage cover from drone data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, forest-ecology

I'm relatively inexperienced with QGIS.

I have a study site where I am testing multiple vegetation removal techniques to reduce fire hazards. I want to collect drone imagery before and 1 year after treatment to see how the treatments compare.

The study site is pretty open and the green foliage stands out against the surrounding terrain. Is there a way in QGIS to measure the vegetation's ground cover percentage from an overhead map made with drone imagery?

The drone we're using is a DJI Phantom 4 RTK with multispectral camera. Has near-infrared, blue-green, red, red edge, and near-infrared lenses.

Comment: Start with this tutorial:  https://www.igismap.com/image-classification-in-qgis-supervised-and-unsupervised-classification/

Comment: @user2856 Thanks, I've updated my question. Yes, the drone can shoot in near infrared.